# Drools rule error "Unexpected global"

Tags: jboss7.x, drools, business-rules

I have business rules implemented in Drools, while executing I get java RuntimeException

```
Unexpected global [myService]
org.drools.common.AbstractWorkingMemory.setGlobal(AbstractWorkingMemory.java:588)
```

What could be the cause?

Rule:

```
rule "Tax Rule"
  when
    calculateTax : calculateTax(
        objOne : objOne,
        objTwo : objTwo,
        objThree : objThree
    );

    objFour : objFour();
    System.out.println("debug");

  then
    ...
end
```

Comment: Can you share your rule? And part of the code where you start the rule engine.

Comment: Thanks Andy, I just figured out the problem, posted the answer.

Comment: I found that if I inserted a global into the kieSession but didn't use the variable in any rule, I also get this error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. I had few System.out.println() and one of them was at the place shown below. Removing that solved the problem.

```
rule "Tax Rule"
  when
    calculateTax : calculateTax(
        objOne : objOne,
        objTwo : objTwo,
        objThree : objThree
    );

    objFour : objFour();
    System.out.println("debug");

  then
    ...
end
```

Comment: You must have neglected the basic caveat of DRL compilation: to check against errors. Clearly: no compiled DRL, thus: no global: thus: failure to set it.

Comment: @laune would you please throw some more lights on how to catch such rule compilation problem as I couldn't see exactly where it was failing, to me it looks like a black box.

Answer (score 12):

To declare and set a global in your DRL, you need to declare it and initialize it:

```
// DRL file
global Service myService

// Java application
StatefulKnowledgeSession session = ...
session.setGlobal("myService", new Service() );
```

Failure to declare the global in the DRL file or a mismatch of the global's name and the first argument in the setGlobal call result in the error  message as posted.

Comment: I checked, I have it correctly declared and no mismatch is there.

Comment: It might help if you were to share your code (the API code to create the global and the rule which is referring to it) rather than just telling us that your code is correct? If it was all correct as you say, I suspect you wouldn't have this problem. ;)

Comment: @Steve, If you read carefully you will find that I never said that my code is correct, I said that the block of code which Laune was referring is correct. Also to bear in mind it is always not possible to share code due to the confidentiality aspect.

Answer (score 1):

This is it, for 5.x; 6.x is somewhat different:

```
KnowledgeBuilderConfiguration kbConfig =
    KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilderConfiguration();
//    kbConfig.setOption( sizeAccFunOption );

KnowledgeBuilder kBuilder =
    KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder( kbConfig );

Resource drl = ResourceFactory.newFileResource( drlPath );

kBuilder.add( drl, ResourceType.DRL );

if( kBuilder.hasErrors() ){
    System.err.println( "### compilation errors ###" );
    KnowledgeBuilderErrors errors = kBuilder.getErrors();
    for( KnowledgeBuilderError err: errors ){
    System.err.println( err.toString() );
    }
    throw new IllegalStateException( "compile errors" );
}
```

Comment: Using KnowledgeBuilder, I occasionally was finding this issue as well. I added the conditional (as @laune specified) to cause a loud failure if there is a rule compilation issue. It wasn't immediately apparent to me that the reason the global failed to set was due to compilation issues in the knowledge base.

Answer (score 1):

In many cases this error means your DRL is compiled with errors, so Drools tells you "Unexpected global" because it can't find any global declaration in empty DRL.

DRL compiler does not throw any exception on errors, instead you should check it yourself using:

```
kieBuilder.getErrors()
```

Answer (score 0):

I find that is the problem of the implement of sessionful session.You can try below code

```
KieSession kieSession = container.newKieSession();
kieSession.getGlobals().set("total",1);
```